# Getting DateTimeOffset value from SQL 2008 to C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetimeoffset

I have a SQL 2008 table with a field called RecDate of type `DateTimeOffset`.

For a given record the value is '2010-04-01 17:19:23.62 -05:00'

In C# I create a DataTable and fill it with the results of

```
SELECT RecDate FROM MyTable.
```

I need to get the milliseconds, but if I do the following the milliseconds are always 0:

```
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
```

What is the proper way to get the value in the RecDate column into the DTO variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps the cast to `ToString()` removes the microsecond info.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx), the SQL Server data type `datetimeoffset` matches C#'s `DateTimeOffset`.  So it should be safe to cast a `datetimeoffset` column to `DateTimeOffset`.

For example:

```
DateTimeOffset dto = (DateTimeOffset) Rows[0][0];
```